# Very Very Large Numbrs in Python

Tags: python, integer

It was my understanding that python could handle integers of arbitrary length.
It handles addition and multiplication very well, but seems to fall apart with division.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec=2**5 
>>> ORIG_NUM=476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833
>>> print(Decimal(ORIG_NUM)/7)
6.8134241248373119570790782479582E+88
>>> print("%.6f" % (Decimal(ORIG_NUM)/7))
68134241248373123068520468160885027682039120236463560535175757714209021725053511199096832.000000
```

I do not want the e notation hence the getcontext().prec attempts.  Also, confused by the %f dropping the decimal?

```
>>> getcontext().prec=2**7
>>>QUOTIENT= (Decimal(476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833)/7)

>>>print(QUOTIENT)
68134241248373119570790782479581551134271725146826890290284253689229460799396205095551690.428571428571428571428571428571428571429
>>>QUOTIENT*7
4.7693968873861185e+89
>>> Decimal(QUOTIENT)*7
Decimal('476939688738611861479643277126195193774273841655244923746230303999463152075374578393677824')
>>> print(Decimal(QUOTIENT)*7)
476939688738611861479643277126195193774273841655244923746230303999463152075374578393677824
>>> print(Decimal(QUOTIENT)*7)==ORIG_NUM
476939688738611861479643277126195193774273841655244923746230303999463152075374578393677824
False
```

Second issue is the numbers do not match up.

Any information on the subject?

Hope that's better...

Comment: Actually, Could you... elaborate?

Comment: This is going places.  What is difficult to understand?  It is all spelled out above?

Comment: I have a number.  I divide that number by 7.  I multiply that quotient by 7, but I do not get the original number.  Math says this is wrong.

Comment: I'd say you have to set the precision to infinite. Buy a lot of RAM first ...

Comment: I think he wanted to ask how to format a number with many decimal places to a string without any special notations.

Comment: @Matthias Why do you say the RAM matters?  You have any data to back that?

Comment: I explicitly state the issue is that the original number and the QUOTIENT re`multiplied do not equal each other.

Comment: @Prine Peregrine: It's basic mathematics. Please try to write down the exact result of `1.0 / 7.0`.

Comment: " range() now behaves like xrange() used to behave, except it works with values of arbitrary size. The latter no longer exists. " Where is the caveat of RAM?  ...http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: How is `range` involved in this?

Comment: Basic mathematics state that the value of the decimal will be less than the value of the divisor.  So the error should be MUCH smaller than it is... I break it down in my answer below.

Comment: Totally confused about the response here.  Legitimate question that had a completely legitimate error that larsmans was able to recognise and correct.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer " In Python 2.x, range and xrange are limited to working with C long and your large integers are just too big for that. This limitation is simply due to the implementation choices made for range and xrange.

In Python 3.x the limitation has been removed and you can perform range() with very large integers. " From my prepost research ... stackoverflow.com/questions/8972002/why-python-isnt-handling-very-large-numbers-in-all-areas

Comment: In your first example, you've asked to convert the `Decimal` to the nearest approximate `float` and use 6 decimals in float ('f') mode. It expands it out by moving the decimal 88 places to the right, but it doesn't continue for the fractional part, and that doesn't matter because everything after 15 digits in the `float` is junk.

Comment: Your 2nd example makes no sense. Somewhere the value for `QUOTIENT` got mixed up. You show the right `QUOTIENT` at first, but when you multiply by 7 you show the results for `float(QUOTIENT) * 7`. Then you show the result for `DECIMAL(float(QUOTIENT)) * 7`, which just expands out a lot of junk (a float has about 15.95 digits of precision).

Comment: @eryksun Sorry, having a hard time understanding what you are talking about.  Never in the code does DECIMAL(float(QUOTIENT) * 7 ever appear?

Comment: I meant based on what the actual value of QUOTIENT *should be*, as you at first show. That times 7 (give 128 digits of precision) is `Decimal('476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833.00000000000000000000000000000000000000')`, but your result for `QUOTIENT*7` is no longer a `Decimal` object at all; it's a float of exactly the value as if you'd somewhere set `QUOTIENT = float(QUOTIENT)`.

Comment: Also, going back to your first example, if you want a `Decimal` representation instead of `float` (again it only has 15 digits of precision), use the new 'advanced' string formatting that uses `Decimal.__format__`. For example: `getcontext().prec=32; format(Decimal(ORIG_NUM)/7, '.6f') == '68134241248373119570790782479582000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000'`. The old '%' formatting converts to `float`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `print(Decimal(QUOTIENT)*7)==ORIG_NUM` fails because the `print` function returns `None`.
2. If you want exact division, use the `Fraction` class.

   ```
   >>> from fractions import Fraction
   >>> x = 476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833
   >>> f = Fraction(x, 7)
   >>> print(f)
   476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833/7
   >>> f * 7 == x
   True
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> (Decimal(QUOTIENT)*7)-476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833
Decimal('24484107799769124335834371765627456691714240528174856926479601142724815991')
```

Crazy huge error.

```
>>> 68134241248373119570790782479581551134271725146826890290284253689229460799396205095551690*7
476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861830
>>> MODD=(Decimal(476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833)%7)
3.000000
>>>TRUNCD_QUO=int((Decimal(476939688738611836995535477357070857939902076027788232031989775824606225595773435668861833)/7))
>>>((TRUNCD_QUO*7)+MODD)==ORIG_NUM
True
```